# Multiple actions on a Single Change Event with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to implement this js in order to fill in different fields on change event of a select field.

```
<select class="form-control" name='brands_list'>
<option value="0">Seleziona il produttore</option>
<?php 
while ($listabrand=mysqli_fetch_array($brands)){
echo '<option value="'.$listabrand[0].','.$listabrand[1].','.$listabrand[2].'">'.$listabrand['0'].' - '.$listabrand['1'].'</option>';
}?>
</select>
```

This is the js to implement. I should add a second action that fill in the input field named 'brand_link' assuming the array value [2]:

```
<script>
    $('select[name="brands_list"]').change(function(){  
    $('input[name="brand_name"]').val($('select[name="brands_list"] option:selected').text().split(' - ')[1]);
    });
    </script>
```

I made several attempts but without results such as

```
<script>
$('select[name="brands_list"]').change(function(){  
$('input[name="brand_name"]').val($('select[name="brands_list"] option:selected').text().split(' - ')[1]);
});

$('select[name="brands_list"]').change(function(){  
$('input[name="brand_link"]').val($('select[name="brands_list"] option:selected').text()[2]);
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Please show one of your attemps.

Comment: One was to duplicate the function and change the action: https://pastebin.com/nBLqnrPJ

Comment: I was able only to display the first field "brand_name" but not "brand_link"

Comment: You should post your attempt in the question rather than on pastebin.

Comment: Always better to show your attempt in the question itself. :-) It would also help to see the structure of the DOM you're manipulating... harder for anyone trying to help you to imagine the DOM elements you're dynamically generating.

Comment: You're right. I implemented my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all within the one function.  The reason your pastebin didn't work is because 1) you aren't operating on the .val() of the selected item (rather the element itself) and 2) you didn't split the value by comma, like you split the .text() by hyphen.

```
$('select[name="brands_list"]').change(function(){
  var $selectedOption = $('select[name="brands_list"] option:selected');
  $('input[name="brand_name"]').val($selectedOption.text().split(' - ')[1]);
  $('input[name="brand_link"]').val($selectedOption.val().split(',')[2]);
});
```

Comment: It's a good practice to save intermediate values to a variable like James did here. 
`A)` it avoids doing DOM queries to get the same element twice, 
`B)` it makes the following code more readable.

Comment: Yes indeed it works now perfectly. Thanks a lot both.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".form-control").change(function()
{ 
     //alert( this.value );
     var sl_value = this.value;
     $('input[name="brand_name"]').val(sl_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="brand_name" value="">
<?php $listabrand=mysqli_fetch_array($brands);?>
<select class="form-control" name='brands_list'>
   <option value="Seleziona il produttore">Seleziona il produttore</option>
   <?php 
      foreach($listabrand as $brand){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $brand;?>"><?php echo $brand;?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

in first step, get dropdown selected value in jquery on change. And save this value in jQuery variable. And then insert this value in textbox using jQuery. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sunil, I am going to test your solution as well.